# Decode enum from json from io.Reader in golang

Tags: go

I have a field in json that is either `abc` or `def` and I want to make sure that when I unmarshal the data it checks that the field only contains either of the 2 valid values, is there a way to do that in golang without adhoc checking?

I know I can do it if I have the json in byte

```
const(
   Enum1 = "abc"
   Enum1 = "def"
)

func (s *MyJsonStruct) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    type Aux MyJsonStruct;
    var a *Aux = (*Aux)(s);
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &a)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if s.Key != Enum1 && s.Key != Enum2 {
        s.Key = ""
        return errors.New("invalid value for Key")
    }
}
```

How to override `UnmarshalJSON` if the input is `io.Reader`

Comment: `UnmarshalJSON` always takes a `[]byte`, never an `io.Reader`. If you pass `io.Reader` to `json.NewDecoder` and then call `Decode` on that, your custom `UnmarshalJSON` will still get a `[]byte` that will hold the contents of that reader.

Comment: ... note also, that if the only reason to implement the custom unmarshaler is so that you can handle the enum, it might, in that case, be more sensible to declare a type for that enum and have that implement the unmarshaler interface instead of the struct.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage.UnmarshalJSON), here is the signature of UnmarshalJson. So the argument of the UnmarshalJson can only be of type `[]byte`

If the input is a `io.Reader`, you can use [NewDecoder](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/stream.go?s=683:720#L21) and [Decode](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/stream.go?s=1425:1472#L39). With that the result can then be pass to UnmarshalJSON.

The other option would be to create another method that will call `UnmarshalJson` under the hood

```
func (s *MyJsonStruct) myUnmarshalJSON(r io.Reader) error {
        type Aux MyJsonStruct;
        var a *Aux = (*Aux)(s);

        d := json.NewDecoder(r)
        d.Decode(&a)
        b := json.Marshal(a)
        s.UnmarshalJson(b)
}

func (s *MyJsonStruct) UnmarshalJSON([]byte) error {

    type Aux MyJsonStruct;
    var a *Aux = (*Aux)(s);

    d := json.NewDecoder(r)
    d.Decode(&a)


    if s.Key != Enum1 && s.Key != Enum2 {
        s.Key = ""
        return errors.New("invalid value for Key")
    }
}
```